# Core Plot in Swift for Beginner

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, core-plot

Hi I just started learning Swift and managed to import CorePlot using CocoaPods, and do the import via the Bridging Header. I also managed to create the axes for my graph:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var graphView: CPTGraphHostingView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

// create graph
var graph = CPTXYGraph(frame: CGRectZero)

graph.paddingLeft = 5
graph.paddingTop = 5
graph.paddingRight = 5
graph.paddingBottom = 5
// Axes
var axes = graph.axisSet as CPTXYAxisSet
var lineStyle = CPTMutableLineStyle()
lineStyle.lineWidth = 2
axes.xAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle
axes.yAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle

self.graphView.hostedGraph = graph
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

1) My question is, how can I label the Axes (using an Array)?

2) Also is there a way to se the distance between the labels proportionally or is this done automatically?

My main issue is that I don't know how to write the Objective C syntax in Swift. There are a lot of objc examples but I would need swift.

Thank you in advance for your patience and help!

Comment: #1: Do you want formatted versions of the label location or arbitrary strings?

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear earlier I just simply meant adding the values to the axes using an array. I have found the solution in objective C which I do not understand, I just started swift. Also if it is possible to set the distance between the labels to be equal and how do I customize it later. Thank you very much!

Comment: I would like to do this in swift: x.axisLabels =  [NSSet setWithArray:customLabels];

Comment: `x.axisLabels = NSSet(array: customLabels)` I haven't tried it, but Swift 1.2 (included with Xcode 6.3 beta) includes a native `Set` datatype that should also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axis `labelingPolicy` controls the tick spacing and labels. With custom labels (`CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone`), it's up to you to give each label a location. If you want tick marks and/or grid lines, you need to set those locations (`majorTickLocations` and/or `minorTickLocations`) separately.

There is a labeling policy demo in the *Plot Gallery* example app that shows the available options.

Comment: Thank you so much Eric! I have tried to add a single label just to try but I seem to be out of luck. I am sure I am missing something: axes.yAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;   var YLabels = [CPTAxisLabel]();    var Label1: CPTAxisLabel = CPTAxisLabel(text: "1", textStyle: axes.yAxis.labelTextStyle);  Label1.offset = axes.yAxis.labelOffset + axes.xAxis.labelOffset;  YLabels.append(Label1);
       axes.yAxis.axisLabels = NSSet(array: YLabels)

Comment: Set the `tickLocation` for the new label, too.

Comment: When I do: Label1.ticklocation = x;   I get: 'CPTAxisLabel' does not have a member named 'tickLocation'.

Comment: `tickLocation` has a capital "L".

Comment: yes i tried but still :/ I think i'm going to have to program my graph in objc its better and the rest in swift. Thank you for your help!

Comment: when I type  'Label1.' all other possible settings come up only tickLocation doesn't

Comment: When using Swift with Core Plot, right now you should use the release-2.0 branch. It changed the API slightly so all of the properties and methods that take an `NSDecimal` (including `tickLocation`) were changed to take `NSNumber`. Just point your podfile at the release-2.0 branch instead of master or a release tag.

Comment: Perfect Now I got tickLocation working! Just please help me just add a single Label, I can take it from there. I don't know whats wrong, see: http://postimg.org/image/80jiek5ij/  (this is how it looks http://postimg.org/image/65ryoh68j/)

Comment: The label is probably there. Increase the left padding on the plot area frame to see it. Also, `axes.yAxis.labelingPolicy = .None`